# How to read Virtualized Registry values from MSIX packaged Electron App

Tags: windows, registry, msix

I have an electron app and trying to convert it to MSIX with Windows's MSIX packaging tool. Tool gives me a chance to put some registry variables to the virtualized registry.

I am trying to read registry values from my MSIX Packaged App. I am sure that they are set right in the MSIX Packaging Tool because I can see them in the [Hover](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/hover.html) app.

But if I intend to read them in the app, I only see the standard variables from the normal Windows Registry. Not the specific ones that I have set in the tool.

I have tried to read them with following modules & ways:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/rage-edit
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/winreg
- and also manualy with `reg query $path` command

None of those helped me, I feel like I only reach to normal Registry, not the Virtualized one.